# Compile time error as 'lvalue required' but not sure why

Tags: c

This code throws an lvalue required compile time error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int k = 8;
    int m = 7;
    k < m ? k++ : m = k;
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

Comment: `clang` says `error: expression is not assignable` with respect to the `m = k` in the ternary operator.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `k < m ? k++ : m = k;`?

Comment: The ternary operator is not an `if` replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator has higher precedence than assignment, that's why your code is equal to `(k < m ? k++ : m) = k;`. Your compiler says that the value in brackets is not assignable.

What you want to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int k = 8;
    int m = 7;
    k < m ? k++ : (m = k);
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
k < m ? k++ : m = k;
```

with the construct you want to assign a value, but you don't. I guess you want something like this:

```
   k =  (k < m) ? k+1 : m;
```

Now you will assign `k` a value depending on the condition `k < m`

> if (k < m) -> k = k+1
>   otherwise  -> k = m

Comment: Isn't `k = k++` UB?

Comment: I am not sure??? Better k+1?

Comment: Yep, `k+1` is ok.

Comment: ok thanks. I edit the answer